How do I download Ubuntu packages in advance for an Ubuntu upgrade (from 24.04 to 24.10, for example)?
I have a desktop computer with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, which I would like to upgrade to Ubuntu 24.10. I also have a laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, that I would also like to upgrade to 24.10. I don't want to have to download all the Ubuntu packages twice, because my Internet connection is slow and metered.
I would like to upgrade to Ubuntu 24.10 on my laptop, and then transfer all the downloads to my desktop computer over a local network connection, so that I can upgrade my desktop computer to Ubuntu 24.10 without having to re-download all the updates over the slow, metered Internet connection.
I know that APT can be configured to keep all downloaded .deb files under /var/cache/apt/ , but it doesn't seem like the downloaded .deb files are kept when upgrading from Ubuntu 24.04 LTS to 24.10.
Even though my question mentioned Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and Ubuntu 24.10 specifically, I'm interested in the answer to this question for any Ubuntu version.

Something like "apt-cacher" or "apt-cacher-ng" ?

Also learn about zsync. I have not downloaded a full ISO in a long time. Each version has changes, but often not the full ISO. I rename ISO in my /ISO folder & zsync new version. It updates ISO & verifies. it. Also if LTS versions works often better to stay with LTS. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZsyncCdImage  Benefits of a release-upgrade (over clean install) by guiverc, but I prefer clean install & restore from backup
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2501145 Note good backups still required https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation
